# SQL Server 2017 Express error

Tags: sql-server

I have the following error when trying to apply a query to my database:

> Failed to load an assembly, Exception: 0x80131040.

Please help

Comment: Noone helps but punishes

Comment: How can we indovinate what assembly you try to use if you don't show us your code?

Comment: There's no any code. I click to apply a query and get an error, I even can't submit a screenshot of this error

Comment: What does it mean "click to apply"? You cannot enter query text in query window? You cannot open SSMS? You cannot excute a query?

Comment: It's very injust to block users who want to get answers even though they may have mistakes in question settings

Comment: Yes just as you describe

Comment: Instead of teaching the other if they should or should not downvote the questions that are impossible to understand, try to IMPROVE your question. It's really unclear.

Comment: As I described WHAT? On WHAT do you make your click? On SSMS icon to launch the program?

Comment: I don't neew any help anymore, thank you

Comment: I have no rights for chat

Comment: Why do you ignore the questions? Can you answer yes/no if you have a problem to LAUNCH ssms?

Comment: Sorry, yes. You are right, in ssms

Comment: So you cannot execute ssms.exe? When you launch it it writes this error? Did you check windows application log for this error?

Comment: yes, no usefull info

Comment: Try te re-install it or it can be a problem of your .Net Framework

Comment: I have many Net framework versions. Maybe the newest to stay

Comment: Update your question with the exact version of your SSMS and tag the question with SSMS. different versions of SSMS use different frameworks

Comment: Very gratefull for your time

Answer (score 0):

It was solved - just put the Service Pack for Sql Management Studio 2016 and NetFrameWork 4.6.2. It was very simple